# vb.netにおけるラムダ式についてご質問

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, vb.net

お世話になります。ラムダ式を使用した際に戻り値が後述の様に想定通りの型になりません。
何かを勘違いしていると思うのですが原因が分かりますでしょうか？

発生状況：
下記の様にラムダ式を書くと、CheckResultはBoolean型となると思っていましたが

```
    Dim CheckResult = Function()
                          Return False
                      End Function
```

実際は下記の様になりました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、上記とは別に参考ソースをもとに Function(x) x + 1のコードで試しましたがInt型にならず似たような結果となりました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以上、よろしくお願いします。

環境：
　開発環境：Visual studio 2017 express
　言語：VB.net
　フレームワーク：.NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: この記事 [ラムダ式の構文](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions#lambda-expression-syntax) の各要件を当てはめてみれば良いと思われます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kunif さんが質問のコメント欄に紹介された記事の最初の方にある「"ラムダ式" は、デリゲートが有効な場所であればどこでも使用できる、名前のない関数またはサブルーチンです」というのを読みましたか？

質問のコードでは、関数を CheckResult と言う変数に代入しているから、インテリセンスは CheckResult が Function だと表示したのでしょう。

Comment: 挙動は正しいということですね。
具体的に、使うときは変数の後ろに（）を使えばいいということだと。